# Workflow for class notes/slides and examples?

Tags: secondary-education

I am teaching high school math in a room with no whiteboard but a projector. I have a tablet that I write on with a stylus and this is projected at the front of the room.

I have been making PowerPoint slides with background material and examples that I work out in real-time with the class by writing on the slides with the stylus.

I have been finding that I run out of room to write on the slides.

I need to find a way to switch from the slides to another software program that gives me a larger "canvas" to write on (e.g. GoodNotes). But that involves rewriting the examples from the slides in the new program, which is annoying and wastes time.

What does your teaching workflow look like in high school math? Do you primarily use slides, the board, a tablet, or a combination?

Comment: No need to rewrite. Goodnotes can import a pdf and then you can write on it, and then add pages. I do that all the time. I'm assuming you can save the slides as pdfs. I teach math in a community college, via zoom. I use goodnotes on an ipad, and use it as my board, but also write on top of things from the textbook. I come into zoom from my computer, and from my ipad.

Comment: To add to this, you can save a powerpoint slides as pdf using the "Save As" option and selecting the filetype pdf.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using PowerPower for presenting your lectures, use software which allows you to display and annotate files (such as .pdf files).

- First, export your PowerPoint slides to .pdf.  Depending on what operating system and version of PowerPoint you are using, this can be done from the "Save As" dialog, the "Export" dialog, or the "Print" dialog (all of these are options under the "File" dropdown).
- Import the files into the program of your choice.  In the comments, Sue VanHattum recommended [GoodNotes](https://www.goodnotes.com/).  Personally, I use [Notability](https://notability.com/).  There are other programs out there---just find one you like.  You can write directly on the slides, or insert extra pages for annotations.  As you get more experience, you will likely find ways of creating slides specifically to be annotated, or find some other workflow which you are happy with.
- As an added bonus, you can export the document as a .pdf (or whatever other format you prefer), then make those files available to students, if you so desire.

---

Another bit of the workflow:  use screenshots to copy things from the screen into the notes.  For example, I often use screenshots to include snippets from the course text, GeoGebra graphs, and bits-and-bobbles from the LMS.

- On an Apple machine, you can hit `CTRL`+`CMD`+`SHIFT`+`4`, then click-and-drag in order to copy a section of the screen to the clipboard.  This can then be pasted into other apps, such as Notability or GoodNote.  Other keyboard shortcuts for screenshotting can be found on [Apple's support pages](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201361) (note: adding `CTRL` to the chord puts the screenshot on the clipboard, rather than saving it to a file.
- Directions for taking screenshots on a Windows machine can be found on [Microsoft's support pages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-snipping-tool-to-capture-screenshots-00246869-1843-655f-f220-97299b865f6b).  I am not a regular Windows user, and have no experience with their screenshot utility, but it *does* exist.
- On tablets, clever phones, and other devices, screenshots can be taken in a variety of ways, which likely depend on the specifics of the hardware and software being used.  For example, on my clever phone (a Google thingy), one takes a screenshot by holding down the power butting, then selecting the "Screenshot" option when the menu pops up.

Once the screen is shot and the captured image stored in the clipboard, it can be pasted into the program of choice using `CMD`+`V` (or `CTRL`+`V` on a Windows box) or via the "Paste" option in the "Edit" dropdown.

Answer (score 4):

If you are happy using the tech, you've gotten some good advice. But. I sense your frustration at the lack of a white board. I'd suggest that the home center type stores (I am looking at Home Depot) have 4 foot by 8 foot sheets of such material in the wall paneling section. It's not sold as a whiteboard, there is no frame, it's just the sheet itself, and it's reasonably priced, I see it listed near me for $20. If you are in the same room for all your classes, 2 nails in the front wall are all you need.

If you are staying on this path - Xander has the solution. During Covid remote, and remote tutoring since, I've gotten to really like Notability. I'd add just one thought to his answer - it offers the ability to link to a folder in Google Drive. I am in my email, and see a pdf my student sent me, and click 'open in' and choose the app. I then switch to Notability, (do what I need to share on Zoom call), write on the PDF as we work together, and when I close out of the app, the updated file, a PDF, is there, in my Google Drive folder to forward from my computer. You can easily create a second copy or erase the added work when presenting to the next classe, but in the end, you have the ability to easily have your work preserved for your own reference or for an absent student.